# The name "Configuration" does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core

When trying to register a database context in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddDbContext<PostDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostDbContext")));
 }
```

I get error

```
The name "Configuration" does not exist in the current context.
```

All code examples are taken from the official Microsoft documentation.
Tutorials -> MVC -> Get started -> Add model.
ASP.NET Core version: 3.1
How fix it?

Comment: Are you setting it in the appsettings.json file; see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) under the heading Sdd a database connection string.

Comment: yes, i added `"ConnectionStrings": {
    "PostContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=PostDbContext-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }` to appsetting.json

Comment: You've got `PostDbContext` in the code above and `PostContext` in the connection string. Make them both the same!

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed that configuration section in your question.

Comment: It isn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not defined a configuration.

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using dotnet 6 and the above solution no longer applies because they got rid of the startup file...  try the below answer.

Configuration.GetConnectionString(string connName) in .NET6 is under builder:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

also AddDbContext() is under builder.Services:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because you have not defined Configuration which is an instance of IConfiguration interface like this-

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
   Configuration = configuration;
}
```

Here Configuration is important to define which checks configuration details.
For Ex.-Configuration.GetConnectionString("Your Connection String") checks the connection string from appsettings.json file to get or set data in database.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to deal with this problems is
Add "builder" before every "Services" u want to build in Program in .NetCore6

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).